# Unable to install python graphviz package

Tags: pip, conda

When I am trying to install **python-graphviz** package on IBM Cloud as part of my final assignment for the course - ML with Python, I'm getting the following errors

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-graphviz (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-graphviz

The command I used is as follows:
**!pip install python-graphviz**

As per the lab instructions, the following commands to install **pydotplus** and **python-graphviz** didn't work.
**#!conda install -c conda-forge pydotplus -y**
**#!conda install -c conda-forge python-graphviz -y**

To summarize,
**!pip install pydotplus** ## THIS IS WORKING.
**#!conda install -c conda-forge pydotplus -y** ## THIS IS NOT WORKING
**!pip install python-graphviz** ## THIS IS NOT WORKING
**#!conda install -c conda-forge python-graphviz -y** ## THIS IS ALSO NOT WORKING.

Please advise me with the right instruction set - whether PIP or CONDA.

Thanks.
Regards,
Vasan S T

Answer (score 4):

Try **pip install graphviz** after upgrading pip.